# libnvinfer.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and TensorFlow 1.13.1. Now I want to integrate TensorRT to improve my model's inference time. I downloaded and extracted TensorRT7's tar, and installed whls of uff and graphsurgeon in its path. I also added its path to the system's LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

However, when I tried to import tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt, it gave me a file not found error. There isn't libnvinfer.so.5 in my TensorRT7's folder but a libnvinfer.so.7 instead.

Does this mean that TensorFlow 1.13.1 doesn't support TensorRT7? Should I use TensorRT5 instead?

Comment: Looks like TensorRT5 support Tensorflow 1.13.1. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/evdcush/TensorFlow-wheels/releases/tag/tf-1.13.1-py37-gpu-10.0) site for more detail. Thanks!